# admin on rest get only top 1000 rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, admin-on-rest

There is a way to restrict the total amount of data fetched in a response in admin-on Rest?

According to my understanding using the **limit** clause we can limit the number of rows in each page but the **get_many** list fetches the whole table and is managed by pagination.

But if I have 2 million rows in backend, how exactly I will restrict that to return only 1000 top rows?

I am using loopback for rest APIs.

Comment: The `GET_MANY` is only used for `ReferenceField`s, can you confirm you're using at least one in your list page ?

Comment: oh sorry typo error I am using get_list

Comment: is it something related to "total"

Comment: `get_list` ? Can you please show some code ?

Comment: case _types.GET_LIST:
        if (!headers.has('x-total-count')) {
          throw new Error('The X-Total-Count header is missing in the HTTP Response. );
        }
        return {
          data: json,
          total: parseInt(headers.get('x-total-count').split('/').pop(), 10)
        };l̥

Comment: The params passed to the `restClient` includes pagination parameters. Use them in your backend to only send the requested page

Comment: according to my understanding and research admin on rest pulls the data for only current  page which is selected in pagination at one time i.e. it doesn't pull the whole data from the table to browser once loaded so even if we have millions and billions of data the browser should not be slow is my understanding correct .just correct me if there is some concern..

Comment: Can you please explain the issue you're facing ? I don't understand it